# Custom template injection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML:

```
<ListView Name="_listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="_itemTemplate">
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

What I would like to get is to create a property in my background code, that will take a custom user control and put it as a dynamic template. Something like this:

```
public UserControl ItemTemplate
{
    set { _itemTemplate.Content = value; }
}
```

So then I can put my control in XAML of window and declare the item template like this:

```
<local:MyCustomControl ItemTemplate="local:ControlThatActsAsItemTemplate"/>
```

How to achieve somtehing like that?

Comment: you need to create a attached dependency property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, that uses dependency property.

In custom `UserControl` declare dependency property that will inject item template to `_listBox`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate",
                                typeof(DataTemplate),
                                typeof(AutoCompleteSearchBox),
                                new PropertyMetadata(ItemTemplate_Changed));

public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
}

private static void ItemTemplate_Changed(
    DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var uc = (MyUserControl)d;
    uc._listBox.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)e.NewValue;
}
```

Now you are free to set a value to that property in hosting window XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:MyUserControl">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropertyName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

`_listBox` in your `UserControl` will gain a custom `ItemTemplate` that will respond to custom interface or class that you want to set as data source.

Answer (score 1):

So far I've found the following, simple solution.

In custom control XAML define the ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="_listBox"/>
```

In code behind create a property:

```
public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return _listBox.ItemTemplate; }
    set { _listBox.ItemTemplate = value; }
}
```

In parent window or control set resources in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then declare the custom control:

```
<local:CustomControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomTemplate}"/>
```

Now you need to have an interface that exposes SomeProperty and data source comprising of such interface instances that you need to set to _listBox.ItemsSource. But this is another story.